# Horizontal tabs

Tags: android, android-widget

Does any one know how to create horizontal tabs with all the tabs being loaded in the same page, i.e. when each tab is select it should be loaded in the same page without cal several activities can it be done in within a single activity use & the horizontal tabs list should not be disturbed in any case when any of the tabs are selected, friends i am need your help in this part if anybody has a code please do share,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand you right,but here is a link to [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) demo which you can use to create horizontal tabs.And about the other part of your question you can use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) for this purpose.Hope it helps.

If this answer don't quit to your question, please provide some more details or examples.